# Possible to both return and free a dynamically allocated array in C?

Tags: c, function, malloc, dynamic-arrays

Is it possible to both return and free a dynamically allocated array?

```
int *mycopy(int *from, int len)
{
    int i;
    int *to;

    to = malloc(len*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        to[i] = from[i]
    }

    return to;

    // how do I free the "to" array?
    // do i even need to, or does the array only have function scope
    // and get deleted when the function exits?
}
```

Or is

```
void mycopy(int *from, int *to, int len);
```

my only option?

The mycopy function is just a simple example but in the real code I want to nest them such as calling it like

```
a = mycopy(mycopy(b, 5), 5)
```

How do I do this without allocating more memory every time the function is called? Thanks.

Comment: You want to copy, then copy the copy, but have the second copying destroy the first copy? Why? That's effectively the same as one copy.

Comment: what you are trying to do just make no sense, you want to return something (to use it we coudl guess) and in the same time want to delete it, so, by definition to make it not usable, could you explain what you want to do precisely instead of what you are trying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you return the array, the calling code must take responsibility for freeing it (and the function must *not* free it).  If you don't return the array, the function *must* free it, but then the function is pointless anyway.  So, the function will not be freeing the array.

If you use:

```
void mycopy(int *from, int *to, int len);
```

the calling code must do the memory allocation.  If you use:

```
void mycopy(int *from, int **to, int len);
```

the function can do the allocation — but it still must not free it.

But the initial function is better: it is fine as written.  You can call it like this:

```
int b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 9, 2 };
int *a = mycopy(b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
...use a...
free(a);
```

Incidentally, you cannot afford to nest calls to your copy function — or, at least, you can't afford to do it using this:

```
a = mycopy(mycopy(b, 5), 5);
```

It would leak memory horribly.  If you must do nested calls (why?), then you'd need:

```
int *c;
int *a = mycopy((c = mycopy(b, 5)), 5);
```

But it would be cleaner and tidier to write:

```
int *a = mycopy(b, 5);
int *c = mycopy(b, 5);
```

That is less error prone, easier to understand, and uses slightly fewer characters to boot!

Comment: So how do I free the array outside of the function? Just free the returned array? In the `a = mycopy(b,5)` example, just free a after calling the funtcion?

Comment: @user1801359 you need to understand that after `free()` you can't use the data anymore. Using the array is valid **until** you call `free()`, so you need to call `free()` when you no longer need that block of memory. This allows a programmer to use the same block of memory throughout the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Yes; given that you call `a = mycopy(b, 5);` you release the allocated memory with `free(a);`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to return AND free a dynamically allocated array *within the same function*, you're contradicting yourself. The purpose of heap (dynamic) allocation is to create an object that persists after a function returns. The receiver has the obligation to free it once it's no longer needed.

Now, in your nesting example, the internal `mycopy(b, 5)` reference is leaked; you're not holding it in a persistent variable. I don't know why it's so important to nest. But it's interesting to discuss, so assuming you insist on nesting: To avoid the memory leak, make it so the *original* copy of the array is the one that is `free()`d *after* the copy is done, so that only the copy survives. Fun! But now, the code still doesn't do anything except waste time. Which brings us back to: Perhaps this is placeholder code. You're probably trying to do something useful, but there's not enough information here to take the appropriate higher level view and re-do the whole strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Note that after all,

```
a = mycopy(mycopy(b, 5), 5);
```

doesn't make sense, because the lost copy, i.e. the one that you will never be able to `free()` is not only lost, but is a useless copy of the original data pointed to by `b`, so this is probably ok with another language where there are no pointers, but in c it just doesn't make sense.

Also, since you can have a single copy of the data and many pointers pointing to it, you normally don't need to copy the data except for modifying a copy of it, but making a copy for reading only, is not necessary, you just use the pointer for that, if you don't want to preserve a copy of the original data, you can also modify it through a pointer instead of creating a copy of it.

To correctly call free, in the caller function where the array was returend call `free(array)` when you are sure you will not need to access the array anymore, for example

```
int *x = mycopy(b, 5);
if (x == NULL)
    pleaseDoSomething_DoNot_Dereference_x();
int *a = mycopy(x, 5);
if (a == NULL)
    pleaseDoSomething_DoNot_Dereference_a();
free(x);
/* Do wahtever you want with a */
free(a);
```

Doing it like you want i.e.

```
a = mycopy(mycopy(b, 5), 5);
```

is possible but incorrect, because you will cause a memory leak, and no there is no way to do it like this, and it's a good thing you will learn in the long term, that the fact that you can't do it like this is a benefit, because this syntax `a = mycopy(mycopy(b, 5), 5);` is very misleading.

**Note**: You don't really need to write a loop to copy the contents, you can just use `memcpy()` from the `string.h` standard header, this would be a robust version of the `mycopy()` function

```
int *mycopy(int *from, size_t length)
{
    int *to;

    to = malloc(length * sizeof(*to));
    if (to == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(to, from, length);
    return to;
}
```

above I said "**robust**" because the code checks the return value of `malloc()` which is `NULL` on failure.

Comment: Marginally neater is `if (to != NULL) memcpy(to, from, length);` as you don't need an extra `return` statement.  I'd also write `int *to = malloc(length * sizeof(*to));` on one line instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

There are times where you need to provide your own function to free memory you have allocated... for instance, on Windows, when you call code that is in a DLL that returns allocated memory to you, you must free it by calling a free that is inside the same DLL or else have a memory leak (best case, heap corruption worst case)... this is because DLLs in MS windows have their own separate heaps from each other and from the main calling program.

This isn't always a bad thing, since the most common case would be an allocated structure that has pointers to other allocated thing in it, so you would likely need a routine to free it properly anyway.

Anyway, to do something like that, you would code the `myfree()` routine in this manner (which I coded in a way to match your code above):

```
void myfree( int** tofree )
{
  if( tofree != NULL ) {
    free( *tofree );
    *tofree = NULL;
  }
}
```

You would call your function and this function in the following manner:

```
int *x = mycopy(b, 5);
// then do some things with x, and after:
myfree(&x);
// x is freed, and set to =NULL
```

Link to relevant MSDN article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

Comment: Intriguing.  Can you provide a URL cross-reference where this behaviour of MS DLLs is described?

Comment: Sure, here is an MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

I've even had this same problem with file handles -- you can fopen in one DLL and you must fclose in the same one, if you don't, you leak open file handles.  The article also mentions this.